# Worklight Project : Error in Xcode Undefined Symbols for Architecture Clang Error

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight project with iPad environment , when i run this i see below linking errors on xcode, Can anyone please help to solve this issue, have tried few answers on stackoverflow but nothing worked.

worklight version :- 6.1.0.01.20140922-2007
Xcode version :- 7.3

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVMainViewController in CDVMainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WLCordovaAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyAppDelegate in .o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVMainViewController in CDVMainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_WLCordovaAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyAppDelegate in .o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a Worklight project for 64 bit architecture.
If you want 64bit support, you need to update your Worklight Studio installation, which is extremely old (2014).

As an IBM customer you can download the latest available iFix from the IBM Fix Central website.